# The copyright symbol (&copy;) is appearing smaller on Mac browser

Tags: html, css, macos, windows-10

The copyright symbol (`&copy;`) is appearing smaller on my Mac browser.
I have tried `&copy;` and  the ::before pseudo element but they are rendered smaller than the text surrounding it on Macs.
Do I have to insert an image to make this work?

```html
<p class="copyright-text">
  &copy;Copyright <span class="current-year"></span> (company name). All Rights Reserved
</p>
```

Comment: Depending on the font, yes, some characters can appear in different sizes on different machines.

Comment: @deceze I did not know this. I have changed the font-family to a more generic one (sans-serif) and it seemed to fix the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: SO was giving me fits, interpreting html examples, so I had to quote them)

1. You don't tell us what font you're using; perhaps it is not installed on your Mac, and it's defaulting to a different font? Inspect and verify that it's displaying the font that you think it is.
2. Try changing the font of the copyright symbol to a fixed-width or type safe font; like Georgia, Consolas, or Verdana, like so:

> // Style
> copyright { font-family: Georgia, Consolas, Verdana }
>
> ```
> <span class="copyright">&copy;</span>
> ```

© Copyright 2021, Amalgamated Bipartisan Conglomerates

```
<p class="copyright-text">
    <span style="font-family: Georgia, Consolas, Verdana">&copy;</span>Copyright <span class="current-year"></span> (company name). All Rights Reserved
</p>
```

3. If you set your character set to UTF-8, you can also try just using the symbol itself (not the `&copy;`) like so:

> ```
> meta charset="UTF-8">
> span class="copyright">©</span>
> ```

```
<p class="copyright-text">
    <span style="font-family: Georgia, Consolas, Verdana">©</span>Copyright <span class="current-year"></span> (company name). All Rights Reserved
</p>
```

© Copyright 2021, Amalgamated Bipartisan Conglomerates

Answer (score 1):

Change `font-size:__;` of symbol to adjust size...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Copyright Symbol Size</title>

    <style>
        #copyright-symbol{
            font-size: 3em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="copyright-text">
        <span id="copyright-symbol">&copy;</span>Copyright <span class="current-year"></span> (company name). All Rights Reserved
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```